# Linux "atop" : MEM total - (used + free + cache + hp) doesn't add up

Tags: memory, atop

Im trying to find out how "free" memory is calculated. I'm using atop in order to see how much each process consumes, and see how much hp / free / cache memory exists. My problem is that I expect that tot - used (including hp) will be equal to (free + cache), but it doesn't.

the way I'm calculating is:

sum up all RSIZE of all processes.
add hptot
from atop:

```
MEM | tot   25G | free   2.5G  | cache 96.9M | dirty  1.7M | buff   6.5M | slab  93.5M  | slrec 16.9M | shmem  3.1M | shrss   0.0M |  hptot  8.1G | numnode    2 |
```

my processes RSIZE sums up to 13.5 G.

so if I take tot - `(used + hp + cache + free)` I get 900 MB left. I wonder where are those? is there some memory usage not presented in this atop summary?